# Flutter, Firebase and gitignore

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-keys

I built an e-commerce app using Flutter, where I used `firebase` inside my app, APIs powered by Google Cloud, I don't know which files should i put in `.gitignore` file or which files should be included in the app overall.

Although I removed `firebase_options.dart`, I'm not sure what else has to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase configuration files:
These files often contain sensitive information and should not be included in version control.

`google-services.json` (for Android)
`GoogleService-Info.plist` (for iOS)
`firebase_options.dart` (if you're using a custom configuration file)

Comment: is firebase_app_id_file.json a confidential file which should be removed from version control as well?

Comment: Yes it should be removed as well.